# Django-Rest/Djoser JWT Verify returning 500 error

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, djoser

I'm having issues verifying if an access token is still valid. I'm using Django-Rest-Framework and Djoser.

I am sending to `jwt/verify` but it is returning a 500 error. `jwt/create` and `jwt/refresh` work without any issues. I've tested through Postman and through my app. Both come back with the 500 code. I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/linkedweb/auth_system) way back when but it appears to work in the tutorial and not on my end. I have changed some things since but haven't touched the djoser stuff.

**Request**

```
export const checkAuthenticated = () => async (dispatch) => {
const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem("access")
if (token) {
const config = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
};

const body = JSON.stringify({ token: token });

try {
  const res = await axios.post(
    `${REACT_APP_API_URL}/auth/jwt/verify/`,
    body,
    config
  );

  if (res.data.code !== "token_not_valid") {
    dispatch({
      type: AUTHENTICATED_SUCCESS,
    });
  } else {
    dispatch({
      type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
    });
  }
} catch (err) {
  dispatch({
    type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
  });
}
} else {
dispatch({
  type: AUTHENTICATED_FAIL,
 });
}
};
```

**Rest Framework and Djoser Settings - Settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ),
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
)

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'AUTH_HEADER_TYPES': ('JWT',),
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'AUTH_TOKEN_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens.AccessToken',
    )
}

DJOSER = {
    'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'USERNAME_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SET_USERNAME_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'USERNAME_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'email/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    # 'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_TOKEN_STRATEGY': 'djoser.social.token.jwt.TokenStrategy',
    'SOCIAL_AUTH_ALLOWED_REDIRECT_URIS': ['http://localhost:3000/google', 'http://localhost:3000/facebook'],
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user_create': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'current_user': 'accounts.serializers.UserCreateSerializer',
        'user_delete': 'djoser.serializers.UserDeleteSerializer',
    }
}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    path('auth/', include('djoser.social.urls')),
    path('', include('clients.urls')),
    path('', include('assessments.urls'))
 ]
```

Comment: please add python error traceback info

Comment: Got me in the right direction. Was able to hook up some error monitoring to the heroku app to get me the trace and was able to solve the issue. Had to do with `rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist`. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out by @Evan,

add

'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist'

in the settings.py under INSTALLED_APPS.

For more info: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/blacklist_app.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).